# How to add a plot legend image in the caption

Tags: labels, plot

I have a plot generated by matlab.
How can I insert the legends in caption like the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I use `pgfplots` a lot, I generally avoid compiling the images directly in my main document, so I coded some small `tikz` macros to do the job independently of the actual `pgfplots` file. It is pretty much my personal taste, but you can customized it the way you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,positioning}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Surface}{m}{%
    (%
    \tikz[baseline=-0.6ex,inner sep=0pt, outer xsep=0pt]{%
        \filldraw[#1,draw=black](0,-0.6ex) rectangle (4mm,0.6ex);%
    }%
    )%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Plot}{ m O{} }{%
    (%
    \tikz[baseline=-0.6ex,inner sep=0pt, outer xsep=0pt] {%
        \draw[line width=1pt,text height = \textheight,#1] plot coordinates {(0,0)} -- plot[#2,mark options={solid}, mark size=2pt] coordinates {(2mm,0)} -- plot coordinates {(4mm,0)};%
    }%
    )%
}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}

    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption{This is a plot \Plot{blue,dotted}[mark=*], this is a surface \Surface{red}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the plot is generated by Matlab, you can export a data file to be plotted with `pgfplots`.

Exporting a matrix from matlab can be done for example with [`csvwrite`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVzer.png)

Once you have the data file, then you can do the following:

```
\begin{filecontents}{exported-from-matlab.dat}
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot table {exported-from-matlab.dat}; \label{norm-dist}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\ref{norm-dist} set of data}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use the references without compiling the `tikzpicture` inside the main document ?

Comment: I once did that with `tikzexternalize`, but I guess it's not what you are really asking ;)
Thanks for your answer, though!

Comment: No, it is not what I am really asking ^^. You're welcome !